# How to change primary key of Room database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

Changing my Primary key required me to update my database version. Is there any way to change my primary key from one field to another using Migration class in Room? If not how do I change my primary key? The following is a snippet of my `Entity`.

```
@Entity(tableName = "weather")
public class Weather {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private final String id;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "city")
    private final String city;
```

I would like to switch from `id` to `city`.

Comment: Just a tip: Room assumes the property names of your entity/pojo are the column names you wish to use. The purpose of the name value in the ColumnInfo annotation, is to set a column name that is different for that property.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

```
Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MyDb.class, "database-name")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build();

static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE weather CHANGE id city VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL;");
    }
};
```

Comment: it's not even vaild a sql statement.

Comment: CHANGE is not a valid SQLite command. Not sure why this is the accepted answer. The best way to do this is to create a new table, copy the data from the old table to new the new table, drop the old table and then rename the new table to the old table.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new table, copy the data from the old table to the new table, drop the old table, then rename the new table to the original name.

Example: rename the primary key `playlist_entry.id` to `playlist_entry.entry_id`:

```kotlin
private val MIGRATION_8_9 = object : Migration(8, 9) {
    // rename playlist_entry.id to playlist_entry.entry_id
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        // create new temp table
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlist_entry_new (entry_id INTEGER NOT NULL, playlist_id INTEGER NOT NULL, tab_id INTEGER NOT NULL, next_entry_id INTEGER, prev_entry_id INTEGER, date_added INTEGER NOT NULL, transpose INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(entry_id))")

        // copy data from old table to new
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO playlist_entry_new (entry_id, playlist_id, tab_id, next_entry_id, prev_entry_id, date_added, transpose) SELECT id, playlist_id, tab_id, next_entry_id, prev_entry_id, date_added, transpose FROM playlist_entry")

        // delete old playlist_entry table
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE playlist_entry")

        // rename new table to playlist_entry
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE playlist_entry_new RENAME TO playlist_entry")
    }
}
```